# Native Android BottomSheet is not appearing in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am building a custom component in Java and trying to display that in React Native but the component is not appearing. I've been looking through forums and documentation for solutions but can't find a solution. I am not sure if it's an issue on the native side or the React Native side. Any help or advice on improvement is highly appreciated.

### Bottom Sheet View

```
public class BottomSheetView extends NestedScrollView {

    private BottomSheetBehavior bSheetBehavior;

    public BottomSheetView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet, this);
        CoordinatorLayout coordinaterLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinate_layout);
        View bottomSheet = coordinaterLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_component);
        bSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
        bSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) PixelUtil.toPixelFromDIP(200));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
    }
}
```

### Bottom Sheet Manager

```
public class BottomSheetManager extends ViewGroupManager<BottomSheetView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "BottomSheet";

    private BottomSheetView bottomSheet;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected BottomSheetView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new BottomSheetView(reactContext);
    }
}
```

### Bottom Sheet Package

```
public class BottomSheetPackage implements ReactPackage {
    private Activity mActivity = null;

    BottomSheetPackage(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public BottomSheetPackage() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = Collections.emptyList();
        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new BottomSheetManager());
    }
}
```

### React Native

```
class BottomSheet extends Component {
       render() {
           return (<BottomSheet style={{height: 200}}/>);
       }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a similar issue. My custom Android component is rendered as simple View without any issue, but when I modify it to ViewGroup, the children are renderered but the parent not. Parent is the native item. Did you fix the issue? thanks.